# Reset jquery ui selectmenu dropdown to default option

Tags: jquery-ui, razor, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have a dropdown select menu rendered via this code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OwnedItemId, Model.Plans, "Select a plan type", new {@class = "selectMenu", id="addPlanSelectmenu"})
```

In the view it looks something like this:

```
<select class="selectMenu" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OwnedItemId must   be a number." id="addPlanSelectmenu" name="OwnedItemId" aria-disabled="false"      style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Select a plan type</option>
    <option value="143863">RetirementSaving (143863)</option>
    <option value="143876">BankAccount (143876)</option>
    <option value="143913">RetirementSaving (143913)</option>
    <option value="143929">RetirementSaving (143929)</option>
    <option value="144030">BankAccount (144030)</option>

    ...
</select>
```

I would like to go to the default option after submitting but I can't make it work. So far I have tried quite a few things, like the one proposed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11031313/1179061), using

```
$('#addPlanSelectmenu').selectmenu("value", "");
```

Funny enough to my understanding if I do something like this

```
$('#addPlanSelectmenu').selectmenu("value", null); //Or an unexisting value
```

it goes back to the last option of the list.

Any idea?

Thanks

Edit: I forgot to mention that I guess a clean way is just adding a value to the default text, but I don't even know if it's possible with these helpers

Edit 2:
I eventually made it work using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10471838/1179061)

Comment: Please note which version of Selectmenu you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$('#addPlanSelectmenu').selectmenu("index", 0);
```

Comment: Thanks @schabluk. No I've tried that before as per the answer I mention in my post and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Similar as resetting - the only solution working to me:

```
$('#resetButton').click(function() {
  $("#Service").selectmenu('destroy');
  $("#Service").prop('selectedIndex',0);
  $("#Service").selectmenu();
})';
```

Comment: Yes I have tried but it was not working. Can it be because of jquery ui versions?

Comment: BTW... you can daisy chain all that together...

$("#Service").selectmenu('destroy').prop('selectedIndex',0).selectmenu();

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, however considering that all the other answers are either incorrect or incomplete, I'll throw in my 2 cents!

All you need to do is

```
$('.selectmenu').val(""); // your default option's value
$('.selectmenu').selectmenu("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in MVC  @Html.DropDownListFor this worked for me using jquery.

```
              if ('#resetButton').click(function(){
                 $("#id").select2('data', null);
               }
```

Comment: or even try this $("#id").select2().select2("val", "place holder value");